# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError when finding next page link with xpath selector

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, capybara, screen-scraping

error when trying to execute, this is a screen scraper I've been working on using capybara and the selenium web driver. Here is the exact error: The given selector # is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred: (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError). This is related to a selector that should find the next page link and click on it. It is a valid xpath selector when reviewing the source but capybara and selenium doesn't agree.

```
require "capybara/dsl"
require "spreadsheet"
require "fileutils"
require "open-uri"


Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_selector = :xpath
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'

class Tomtop
  include Capybara::DSL

  def initialize
    @LOCAL_DIR = "data-hold/images"
    @excel = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    @work_list = @excel.create_worksheet
    @row = 0
    FileUtils.makedirs(@LOCAL_DIR) unless File.exists? @LOCAL_DIR
  end

  def go
    visit_main_link
  end

  def retryable(options = {}, &block)
    opts = { :tries => 1, :on => Exception }.merge(options) #possible bug (remove this line and take options from options hash)

    retry_exception, retries = opts[:on], opts[:tries]

    begin
      return yield
    rescue retry_exception
      retry if (retries -= 1) > 0
    end

    yield
  end

  def visit_main_link
    visit "http://www.example.com/clothing-accessories?dir=asc&limit=72&order=position"
    @results = all("//h5/a[contains(@onclick, 'analyticsLog')]")
    while page.has_selector?("//td[contains(@class, 'pages')]//a[img/@alt='Next Page']")
      retryable(:tries => 1, :on => OpenURI::HTTPError) do
      find.first("//td[contains(@class, 'pages')]//a[img/@alt='Next Page']").click
      @results = all("//h5/a[contains(@onclick, 'analyticsLog')]")
      @results.each do |a|
        @links << a[:href]
        end
          @links.each do |link|
            visit link
            save_item
          end
        @excel.write "inventory.csv"
      end
    end 
  end

  def save_item
    data = all("//*[@id='content-wrapper']/div[2]/div/div")
    data.each do |info|
      @work_list[@row, 0] = info.find("//*[@id='productright']/div/div[1]/h1").text

      price = info.first("//div[contains(@class, 'price font left')]")
      @work_list[@row, 1] = (price.text.to_f * 1.33).round(2) if price

      @work_list[@row, 2] = info.find("//*[@id='productright']/div/div[11]").text

      @work_list[@row, 3] = info.find("//*[@id='tabcontent1']/div/div").text.strip

      color = info.all("//dd[1]//select[contains(@name, 'options')]//*[@price='0']")
      @work_list[@row, 4] = color.collect(&:text).join(', ')

      size = info.all("//dd[2]//select[contains(@name, 'options')]//*[@price='0']")
      @work_list[@row, 5] = size.collect(&:text).join(', ')

      sku = File.basename(info.find("//*[@id='content-wrapper']/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")['href'])
      @work_list[@row, 6] = sku.gsub!(/\D/, "")#.join(([*('A'..'Z'),*('0'..'9')]-%w(0 1 I O)).sample(4).join)

      @work_list[@row, 7] = File.basename(info.find("//*[@id='content-wrapper']/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")['href'])

      imagelink = info.all("//*[@rel='lightbox[rotation]']")
      @work_list[@row, 8] = imagelink.map { |link| File.basename(link['href']) }.join(', ')  

      images = imagelink.map { |link| link['href'] }
      images.each do |image|
        File.open(File.basename("#{@LOCAL_DIR}/#{image}"), 'w') do |f|
          f.write(open(image).read)
        end
      end
      @row = @row + 1
    end
  end
end

tomtop = Tomtop.new
tomtop.go
```

Comment: What line is this failing on?

Comment: line 46 seems to be the problem but a few lines above with the same xpath selector evaluates fine: page.has_selector?("//td[contains(@class, 'pages')]//a[img/@alt='Next Page']")

Comment: What browser are you running against?

Comment: using the selenium web driver which runs with a variant of firefox I believe

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is here:

```
find.first("//td[contains(@class, 'pages')]//a[img/@alt='Next Page']").click
```

More specifically:

```
a[img/@alt='Next Page']
```

I've never seen this notation in xpath before, so it's my guess that it's invalid.  To me, this means:

> Find `<a img='Next Page' alt='Next Page' />`

But since you match attributes on `@` i'm sure it's incorrect notation.

Fix your selector to match what you need it to.  For example, if you are trying to find the image that is under an `<a />` then you should use

```
a/img[@alt='Next Page']
```

Another recommendation that i should make, is to use CSS selectors.  They are [faster, and more readable.](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/)

Comment: I don't understand why it is invalid when it can be found on the page in question. I will try it with css selectors; could you provide a reccomendation for the next page link on the following page: http://www.tomtop.com/clothing-accessories?dir=asc&limit=72&order=position

Comment: sure thing! Your selector would be: `td.pages li:nth-child(6) a[href*='&p']` though keep in mind that this selector finds _both_ pagination sections. I'm not sure if your test calls for differentiating these

Comment: i'm using find.first to handle that so yours would be: find.first(:css,"td.pages li:nth-child(6) a[href*='&p']").click but it still throws the same error. (using xpath as the default selector so switching back to css)

Comment: why does this evaluate as true if the selector is not valid?: page.has_selector?("//td[contains(@class, 'pages')]//a[img/@alt='Next Page']") ; this is eating me alive.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that xpath. The error probably just means that it can't find it.

Comment: But it is clearly in the source and I believe I'm using all the methods properly so why wouldn't it be found by capybara?

Comment: Because it's not there anymore. With selenium, an element can be there one moment and then not a microsecond later. If you want the elements to stay put you should probably parse the html with nokogiri and use that.